# Alcohol-related crime statistics

Tags: database, statistics

Where can I get statistics or data on alcohol-related crime by state preferably 2017 or newer? I am looking for either a full dataset that would contain drunk driving rates and violent crime involving alcohol or just state-level statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of Snowflake's Data Exchange Partners, data.world, has some of this data available (this dataset has driving incidents but not other violent incidents):

https://data.world/cdc/impaired-driving-death-all

The original dataset from the CDC is available here (last updated 2 Sept 2019):

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/impaired-driving-death-rate-by-age-and-gender-2012-all-states-587fd

If you use the Snowflake Data Exchange to source the data, it will automatically show up in your database as data.world updates the statistics from the source. Good luck!